# Angular 6 resolve always undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use my service for getting values from database server to display onscreen. I do so with a resolver for the service as the database is a little slow sometimes.

But the data `this.route.data.subscribe` gives me is always undefined no matte what I tried. I checked if the service is getting a response from the server, and it does. Weird thing is that if I use the service directly everything works fine.

Component where the data is processed:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TempsService, Temps } from '../../temps.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-temps',
  templateUrl: './temps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./temps.component.scss']
})
export class TempsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() solar: boolean;
  solarURL: string = 'tempSolar';
  waterURL: string = 'tempWater';
  tempSolar: number;
  tempWater: number;
  timestamp: string;

  temps: Temps;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private tempService: TempsService) { }

  showWaterTemp() {
    this.tempService.getTemp(this.waterURL)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.tempWater = data.rawValue;
        this.timestamp = data.time;
      });
  }

  showSolarTemp() {
    this.route.data
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.tempSolar = data.rawValue;
      });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.solar) {
      this.showSolarTemp();
      this.showWaterTemp();
    }
  }
}
```

This is he routing module (I am using the NowUI Angular theme by CreativeTim, so most things were done by them):

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from '../../user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { TableListComponent } from '../../table-list/table-list.component';
import { TypographyComponent } from '../../typography/typography.component';
import { IconsComponent } from '../../icons/icons.component';
import { MapsComponent } from '../../maps/maps.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from '../../notifications/notifications.component';
import { TempsComponent } from '../../dashboard/temps/temps.component';
import { TempResolver } from '../../temp-resolver/temp-resolver.resolver';

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: TempsComponent, resolve: { temps: TempResolver } }
    ] },
    { path: 'user-profile',   component: UserProfileComponent },
    { path: 'table-list',     component: TableListComponent },
    { path: 'typography',     component: TypographyComponent },
    { path: 'icons',          component: IconsComponent },
    { path: 'maps',           component: MapsComponent },
    { path: 'notifications',  component: NotificationsComponent }
];
```

And this is how the resolver looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Temps, TempsService } from '../temps.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TempResolver implements Resolve<Temps> {

  test: number;
  constructor(private tempService: TempsService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Temps> {
    this.tempService.getTemp('tempSolar').subscribe(data => {this.test = data.rawValue})
    alert(this.test)

    return this.tempService.getTemp('tempSolar');
  }
}
```

In my opinion this is a really strange problem.

UPDATE:
This is the service for getting the data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TempsComponent } from './dashboard/temps/temps.component'

export interface Temps {
  id: string;
  time: string;
  date: string;
  name: string;
  rawValue: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class TempsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  url: string = window.location.hostname;

  tempUrl = 'http://' + this.url + ':3000/latestTime/';

  getTemp(temp: String) {
    return this.http.get<Temps>(this.tempUrl + temp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried adding the resolve to the dashboard component in which the Temp component is used. And now it works like a charm.
It looks now like this:

```
{ path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent, resolve: {temps: TempResolver} }
```

instead of this:

```
{ path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: TempsComponent, resolve: { temps: TempResolver } }] 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
   this.route.data
  .subscribe(({temps}) => {
    this.tempSolar = temps;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, avoid subscribing to `getTemps()` in `resolve()`, simply return an `Observable<whatever>`. Keep in mind the asynchronous nature of `getTemps()`. `alert(this.test)` will almost always execute before `getTemps()` has been completed, basically guaranteeing it will be `undefined` at the time of alert.

Simply return `getTemp()` so that it returns an `Observable<Temps>`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Temps, TempsService } from '../temps.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TempResolver implements Resolve<Temps> {
  constructor(private tempService: TempsService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Temps> {
    return this.tempService.getTemp('tempSolar');
  }
}
```

Then in the component extracting the `rawValue` property as needed:

```
showSolarTemp() {
  this.route.data.subscribe((data: { temps: Temps }) => {
    this.tempSolar = data.temps.rawValue;
  });
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blfsay) showing the functionality in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: There will be another value added later so your second solution is unfortunatly not working. For the first solution, I tried this but just get `TypeError: data.temps is undefined`... I am really frustrated right now...

Comment: BTW the response that the service is getting from the database looks like this: `{"id":"00_0010_1122_10_0100_000_2_0","time":"22:11","date":"21.02.2018","name":"Temperature sensor 1","rawValue":-1.4000000000000001}`

Comment: Updated the question above.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a StackBlitz example showing the functionality in action. You can at minimum use that StackBlitz if that does not help and update it with the nested dashboard feature routes/components. Thanks!